# JXDatePicker Throws a Null Pointer Exception when I create a new Object

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I have been trying to add a JXDatePicker using the following line

```
    JXDatePicker dobPicker = new JXDatePicker(new Date());
```

However I am getting this Null Pointer Exception

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1026)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.UIManagerExt$UIDefaultsExt.getResourceCache(UIManagerExt.java:160)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.UIManagerExt$UIDefaultsExt.getFromResourceBundle(UIManagerExt.java:144)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.UIManagerExt$UIDefaultsExt.access$000(UIManagerExt.java:113)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.UIManagerExt.getColor(UIManagerExt.java:427)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.UIManagerExt.getColor(UIManagerExt.java:401)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicMonthViewUI.installDefaults(BasicMonthViewUI.java:320)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicMonthViewUI.installUI(BasicMonthViewUI.java:264)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setUI(JXMonthView.java:776)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.updateUI(JXMonthView.java:786)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.<init>(JXMonthView.java:318)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.<init>(JXMonthView.java:255)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.initMonthView(JXDatePicker.java:359)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.init(JXDatePicker.java:351)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.<init>(JXDatePicker.java:279)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.<init>(JXDatePicker.java:247)
```

I have Imported all the classes and other components are doing fine, Im I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I am a bit confused to. I have created a JFrame and all I am doing is add a JXDatePicker. Thats it, the application throws that error when I run it. When I substitute it with a JLabel it runs fine.